# MySQL triggers different database different server

Tags: mysql, database, remote-server, database-trigger

I have two sites in two different servers, one live site and another dev site. I want to set a MySQL trigger in the live database table which updates the dev database table in the time of Insert, Update, Delete happen. How can I set a trigger between these two remote server DB?

Answer (score 0):

This is known as Replication.

Please refeer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html